# How to use docutils to convert .rsts to htmls?

Tags: python, html, documentation-generation, restructuredtext, docutils

I downloaded a util(cmake,actually) tar,and it's doc was written as .rst files with structure like blow.After googling,I know docutils(a python package) can convert these files to htmls,so installed it ,but I can't find a way to to do it?please tell me,is there any simple command to do it?How?

//doc files structure(generated by ls -l under ubuntu)

```
command
generator
include
index.rst
manual
module
policy
prop_cache
prop_dir
prop_gbl
prop_sf
prop_test
prop_tgt
release
variable
```

Comment: From this description, it is not clear whether the conversion should be done with a Docutils front end tool like `rst2html5` or with `sphinx`. Normally the downloaded util's README or INSTALLATION file should give advise on converting the documentation. An error like `Unknown directive type "toctree".` indicates that `sphinx` is the right tool.

Answer (score 0):

The `docutils` [documentation](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/README.html#quick-start) tells you what to do. In your case, you want the `rst2html.py` command, which should have been installed in your `PATH` when you installed the module. Run

```
rst2html.py --help
```

to see what the command-line options are.

Comment: Actually,I have installed sphinx also and tried to run: rst2html.py index.rst index.html,but got many errors like:index.rst:16: (ERROR/3) Unknown directive type "toctree".

Comment: Your errors of that kind are because those are Sphinx-specific directives, which docutils will not translate (only the ReST-specific ones).  It's a bummer I just ran into too.

Comment: You cannot execute a Python file, so this will not work at all.

Comment: @1313e yes you can, if the executable bit is set - `chmod +x myfile.py`. When `docutils` is installed, `rst2html.py` is executable. On Windows (which this question isn't about), `.py` files are by default associated with the Python launcher. If I didn't know that what I was recommending would work, I wouldn't have answered the question.

Comment: Thanks for making my point. Yes, on Windows, you cannot execute Python files. This question does not specify the OS, thus all OSs must be taken into account.

Comment: @1313e from the question, just above the code box: *generated by ls -l under ubuntu*. I'm not going to argue any more about this.